# Problem with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I don't know how those coordinates in brackets work. I mean, if I got `$(a,b)$` it is like in Euclidean coordinates. But in below example I can't deduce how it works.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {A};
  \node at ( 210:2)   {B};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {C};
  \node  {\tiny{$A \cap B \cap C$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! All the coordinates you have in the example are polar, i.e. they have a `:` in it. E.g. in `( 90:1.2)` `90` is the angle and `1.2` the radius. If you use `(1,2)` with a comma, then these will be Cartesian coordinates. (BTW, there is a package for Venn diagrams, `venndiagram`.)

Comment: I wanted to do Venn diagram on my own, and I think it was worth because I learned something. :D Thank you, I understand everything now.

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, you may want to use `circle[radius=2cm]` instead of `circle (2)`, `\node  {$\scriptstyle A \cap B \cap C$};` since `\tiny` is not valid in math mode, and use math mode for the other nodes, e.g. ` \node at (90:2)    {$A$};`.